# need help on submitting hudi delta streamer job via apache livy

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, livy, apache-hudi

I am little confused with how to pass the arguments as  REST API JSON.

Consider below spark submit command.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hudi:hudi-utilities-bundle_2.11:0.5.3,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4 \
 --master yarn \
 --deploy-mode cluster \
 --num-executors 10 \
 --executor-memory 3g \
 --driver-memory 6g \
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/varadarb_ds_driver.hprof" \
 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/varadarb_ds_executor.hprof" \
 --queue hadoop-platform-queue \
 --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR \
 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1072 \
 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 \
 --conf spark.task.cpus=1 \
 --conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
 --conf spark.task.maxFailures=10 \
 --conf spark.memory.fraction=0.4 \
 --conf spark.rdd.compress=true \
 --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=200m \
 --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
 --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1 \
 --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
 --conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false \
 --conf spark.ui.port=5555 \
 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=3g \
 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=120s \
 --conf spark.network.timeout=600s \
 --conf spark.eventLog.overwrite=true \
 --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
 --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs:///user/spark/applicationHistory \
 --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=10 \
 --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive \
 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100 \
 --driver-class-path $HADOOP_CONF_DIR \
 --class org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer \
 --table-type MERGE_ON_READ \
 --source-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.sources.JsonKafkaSource \
 --source-ordering-field ts  \
 --target-base-path /user/hive/warehouse/stock_ticks_mor \
 --target-table stock_ticks_mor \
 --props /var/demo/config/kafka-source.properties \
 --schemaprovider-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.schema.FilebasedSchemaProvider \
 --continuous
```

How to pass it as a JSON to Livy server. How to pass the jar files as files and other configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting here, if it may help someone.

WE found out that we can pass args as a list in a http request (to the livy server).
in args, we can pass all the hudi related confs like ["key1","value1","key2",","value2","--hoodie-conf","confname=value"... etc]. We are able to submit jobs via livy server.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69655536/5153067 on how you can pass the json to LIVY endpoint